# element chapter: validity error : Element chapter content does not follow the DTD, expecting

Tags: xml, dtd, xmllint

I have `openembedded` that has a docs directory and the README instructs me to run

```
make <type>
```

type can be pdf,dvi, html,txt, etc etc

`xsltproc` and `docbook-utils` are required to generate the documentation.
Both are installed.

U have `make pdf` and the error generated was:

```
./usermanual.xml:91: element chapter: validity error : Element chapter content
 does not follow the DTD, expecting (beginpage? , chapterinfo? , (title , 
subtitle? , titleabbrev?) , (toc ...
title CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA CDATA 
CDATA CDATA CDATA ) 
Document ./usermanual.xml does not validate
make: *** [lint] Error 3
```

I have absolutely `0`-experience with `XML` files, `dtd`files. And I suspect a clash in version of `docbook-utils` I have and the source requires.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is truncated, so it's not possible to know exactly what the requirements for the `<chapter>` element are, but it says that the contents of your `<chapter>` element do not match the DTD and because of that will not validate. It details the problem stating that the `<chapter>` element requires certain elements, in a certain order.

The commas in the error message mean a *sequence*. From the part of the error message that is shown above it is possible to know that, inside a `<chapter>` element:

- You can have **zero or one** `<beginpage>` elements, and if present, it must come first.
- You can have **zero or one** `<chapterinfo>` elements, and if present, it must come before the other elements but after `<beginpage>` (if present).
- Following `<beginpage>` and `<chapterinfo>`, you **must** have a `<title>` and you **can** have at most one `<subtitle>` or `<titleabbrev>`.

If any of the rules above are not being followed in your source XML, validation will fail.

The rest of the DTD description of the message seems to be abbreviated, so it's not possible to conclude anything. You should check the full DTD to know what is wrong. It's not so difficult to read a DTD. Most ot the time you just have to understand *sequences* which are comma separated names: `<!ELEMENT name (title?, first, middle*, last)>` (`name` allows zero or one `title`, must have a `first`, may have zero or unbounded `middle` and must have `last`, in this order), and *choices* which are separated by `|`: `<!ELEMENT contact (email | phone)>` (`contact` must contain either `email` or `phone`) or `<!ELEMENT contact (email | phone)*>` (`contact` can be empty, can contain many choices of `email` or `phone`, in any order).

You might want to read a quick [DTD tutorial](http://www.ldodds.com/delta/dtd_guide.html).

Comment: The explanation is good. I think it would be helpful if you provided a well-formed XML document with chapter information. I'm revisting old DocBook sources. Stuff that used to validate no longer does. Ugh...